# Xamarin.iOS App - TestFlight Build Crashing without Logging Anything

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, crash, testflight

I have been using TestFlight for several months now to distribute new builds to our beta testers and for the most part I haven't had any problems. As of yesterday (4/11/2017) however, the app is crashing immediately after launch on all of our test devices - without generating any crash reports, so I have no idea how to identify the problem.

I thought that the issue may have been related to using HockeyApp for crash logging (although I have been using that for weeks without any problems), but after removing the related code the crashes are still occurring.

The app runs fine in the simulator, and runs fine on all of our test devices if installed directly through Xamarin Studio (both debug and release versions are working). These crashes are only occurring installing the app through TestFlight. Can anyone offer any suggestions as to how I can track this problem down?

Comment: Had the same issue a while ago. Reason for this was that the linker was set to "Full" on the AppStore build configuration. To track that down I exchanged the signing key with the one used for debug configuration and run that configuration locally. I was now able to reproduce the crash and did some further investigation until I found the root cause.